Cannot run short-ranged nonbonded interactions on a GPU because no GPU is detected
I use these commands to create a build directory and configure the build:
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DGMX_GPU=CUDA \
         -DCMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER=/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc \
         -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/gromacs \
         -DGMX_BUILD_OWN_FFTW=ON -DGMX_MPI=OFF

and when I run this command for running a simulation
gmx mdrun -deffnm nvt -nb gpu

it is giving me this error:
Fatal error:
Cannot run short-ranged nonbonded interactions on a GPU because no GPU is detected.

please help me if you know.

Please [edit] your question and give us (a lot) more context. First of all, what is your operating system? Next, what are you building? Where did you download it from?  How can we try to reproduce this? What is your hardware? Do you have an NVIDIA graphics card? Is it compatible with whatever you are using? Are those the only commands you ran? Did you skip make install and sourcing /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC as described in the documentation?
